# Bad Request in Discord.js (Node) and cant find out whats causing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Im coding a bot in Discord.js (Node) and I'm trying to send an embed with the server info, I've got all the code but it keeps causing a Bad Request and I've tried everything I know here's the code:

```
var FieldsData = [{ name: "Channels", value: msg.guild.channels.size }, { name: "Emojis", value: msg.guild.emojis.size }, { name: "Members", value: msg.guild.members.size }, { name: "Owner", value: msg.guild.owner }, { name: "Roles", value: msg.guild.roles.size }, { name: "Region", value: msg.guild.region }, { name: "Id", value: msg.guild.id }, { name: "Icon", value: msg.guild.iconURL }, { name: "Created At", value: msg.guild.createdAt }];
msg.channel.send('', {
    embed: {
        color: 37119,
        title: "Server info for " + msg.guild.name,
        fields: FieldsData
    }
});
```

I've tried the message with just one field and it works,
I've tried it will each field by themselves and it works
but when I put them all together they make a Bad Request,
I've checked every line, every character and I'm just
stumped at what could possibly be causing this,
the max fields is 25 and I don't have that many,
all the variables are valid, none produce 'Null' or 'Undefined',
I've tried different setups of the code layout,
I've tried adding/removing parts, editing parts, replacing bits
here and there but to no avail I cant get it to work at all.

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 hours, I've searched online, docs, etc

Please Note: I'm not that advanced with javascript so if i've made a big mistake then don't be surprised.

"msg" is the object of the message, Example:

```
Bot.on('message', function (msg) { /*Stuff*/ });
```

I hope I've explained this enough, I'm using the LATEST version of Discord.js at the time of posting this and I'm not using ANY other extensions, packages, etc

Comment: Try using `RichEmbed` instead

Comment: @Wright i dont wanna use RichEmbed, i wanna use the default embed

Comment: Why wouldn't you?

Comment: i have scripts that require the use of objects, and they are pre made

Comment: and i wanna use the Default Embed for other reasons

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER:

Now, don't just ignore this post after I say this (actually read my reasons, the whole thing), but please just use a `Rich Embed`

---

LONG ANSWER:

First of all, I strongly suggest using `Rich Embeds`, as it is easier to play with and edit. Anyways, here:

The first suggestion comes from your message event. In ES6, we now have arrow functions which look like this `(arg1, arg2) => {doSomething();}`, and using this new feature, your message event handler should look more like this:

```
client.on('message', msg => {

  //Do my thing with that msg object

});
```

Now back to the point.

1. Objects are weird k? I believe that this: `"Server info for " + msg.guild.name` is not allowed. I don't know why, but when I tried to use a variable to display my bot's version, it gave me an error too. So if you want to fix that you have two options:

   - Recommended: Use Rich Embeds
   - Not Recommended: Use `${myVar}` instead (Not Tested)
2. Don't overcomplicate. What is this: `('',` You can  just do msg.channel.send({embed:{}});
3. You don't just use variables for the sake of it. What is the point of using FieldsData? It is only used once, and why can't you just do:

   ```
   msg.channel.send({
       embed: {
           color: 37119,
           title: "Server info for " + msg.guild.name,
           fields: [{name: "Channels", value: msg.guild.channels.size}, { name: "Emojis", value: msg.guild.emojis.size }, { name: "Members", value: msg.guild.members.size }, { name: "Owner", value: msg.guild.owner }, { name: "Roles", value: msg.guild.roles.size }, { name: "Region", value: msg.guild.region }, { name: "Id", value: msg.guild.id }, { name: "Icon", value: msg.guild.iconURL }, { name: "Created At", value: msg.guild.createdAt }]
       }
   });
   ```

---

VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:

Now, you don't give any valid reason why you don't want to use `Rich Embeds`, because a rich embed is also an object. ;-; So just use a rich embed.

> i have scripts that require the use of objects, and they are pre made

I wonder how you get access to your embed if its not stored.... Very interesting.